# Replace an id by empty character in sql dump

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

My sqldump is like that

```sql
LOCK TABLES `mytable` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mytable` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (8118,0,'E4B62B0A-8FFD-4FB9-A7A6-310D0A023426',NULL,'34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD','34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD',NULL,'file','88201019',NULL,88201019,'/Nextcloud.png',19,1705051444,1,'2024-04-11 00:00:00',NULL,0,NULL,0,'Partage de test',0,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (8119,0,'E4B62B0A-8FFD-4FB9-A7A6-310D0A023426',NULL,'34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD','34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD',NULL,'file','63376796',NULL,63376796,'/Readme (2).md',19,1705051504,1,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0,'Partage de test sur le groupfolders',0,NULL,NULL,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mytable` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

In this file I have some `sed` to do but one I can't find a solution. I want to replace the first column that is an autoincrement number by an empty character:

Exemple

- Original line:

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (8118
  ```
- Desired result:

  ```sql
  INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (''
  ```

And that in all lines that start with `INSERT INTO ...`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is `sed` the only acceptable tool, or is any standard text-processing tool an option?

Comment: Wouldn't that change cause the actual `INSERT` statement to fail? The type of the first field is wrong.  What's the schema for `mytable`?

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is an option, the following program should do:

```shell
awk 'index($0,"INSERT INTO")==1{sub(/\([[:digit:]]+,/,"(\047\047,")} 1' input.dump
```

This would check if a line starts with `INSERT INTO`, and substitute the first occurence of `(<digit>,` with `(''`, where the single-quotes are expressed via ASCII escape sequence (otherwise they would be misinterpreted at shell-level). All other lines are printed unchanged.

Since `awk` by default doesn't modify the input file, you either have to redirect to a temporary output file and rename, or (if your `awk` implementation supports it), use the `-i inplace` option for direct modification.

---

If it must be `sed`, then the following should work:

```shell
sed -E '/^INSERT INTO/s/\([[:digit:]]+,/('\'\'',/' input.dump
```

Here, you can use the `-i` option to modify the input file directly.

Comment: If (big if) the OP's data really are as simple as they show you could just do `sed "s/([^,]*/(''/"`

Comment: assuming OP's sqldump file could contain `INSERT` statements for multiple tables ... should probably consider adding `'mytable'` to the `sed` script to insure only records for `mytable` are updated

Comment: the format of the `INSERT` statement is `INSERT [INTO] [(column_list)] VALUES (values_list)`; while OP's sample does not include the optional `(column_list)` it would be more complete to include a match for `VALUES` in the `sed` script

Answer (score 0):

If this, using any sed, isn't all you need:

```
$ sed "s/([^,]*/(''/" file
LOCK TABLES `mytable` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mytable` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES ('',0,'E4B62B0A-8FFD-4FB9-A7A6-310D0A023426',NULL,'34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD','34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD',NULL,'file','88201019',NULL,88201019,'/Nextcloud.png',19,1705051444,1,'2024-04-11 00:00:00',NULL,0,NULL,0,'Partage de test',0,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES ('',0,'E4B62B0A-8FFD-4FB9-A7A6-310D0A023426',NULL,'34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD','34F1E16B-5095-4BB1-AF6A-9236D73BE7CD',NULL,'file','63376796',NULL,63376796,'/Readme (2).md',19,1705051504,1,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0,'Partage de test sur le groupfolders',0,NULL,NULL,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mytable` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

then edit your question to show more truly representative sample input/output including cases where the above doesn't work.